# Error with FourSquare authentification

Tags: android, foursquare

I am trying to create android app with FourSquare api. I used EasyFoursquare4Android Library, but I am getting an error when I try to use it.

Here is the full logcat trace for this error.

```
952-7520/com.example.mikhail.testfsq W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=26: thread exiting      with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
03-25 23:20:57.609    6952-7520/com.example.mikhail.testfsq E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:69)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:232)
at com.example.mikhail.testfsq.MyActivity.onError(MyActivity.java:50)
at com.example.mikhail.testfsq.tasks.AccessTokenRequest.doInBackground(AccessTokenRequest.java:74)
at com.example.mikhail.testfsq.tasks.AccessTokenRequest.doInBackground(AccessTokenRequest.java:22)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-25 23:21:04.890    6952-6952/com.example.mikhail.testfsq E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.mikhail.testfsq.MyActivity has leaked    window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b6110 that was   originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mikhail.testfsq.MyActivity    has leaked window    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b6110 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at com.example.mikhail.testfsq.tasks.AccessTokenRequest.onPreExecute(AccessTokenRequest.java:38)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
at com.example.mikhail.testfsq.FoursquareDialog$FoursquareWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FoursquareDialog.java:131)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:218)
at      android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:337)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code

```
public class AccessTokenRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

private Activity mActivity;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private AccessTokenRequestListener mListener;

public AccessTokenRequest(Activity activity, AccessTokenRequestListener listener) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
    mProgress.setMessage("Getting access token ...");
    mProgress.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String code = params[0];
    String token = "";
    // Check if there is a parameter called "code"
    if (code != null) {
        try {
            // Call Foursquare again to get the access token
            JSONObject tokenJson = executeHttpGet("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token"
                    + "?client_id="
                    + FoursquareConstants.CLIENT_ID
                    + "&client_secret="
                    + FoursquareConstants.CLIENT_SECRET
                    + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                    + "&redirect_uri="
                    + FoursquareConstants.CALLBACK_URL
                    + "&code="
                    + code);

            token = tokenJson.getString("access_token");

            //saving token
            Log.i("Access Token", token);
            SharedPreferences settings = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(FoursquareConstants.SHARED_PREF_FILE, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(FoursquareConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            Log.e("LoginTest", "Getting Access token failed", exp);
            mListener.onError(exp.toString());
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Unknown login error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        mListener.onError("Unknown login error");
    }
    return token;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String access_token) {
    mProgress.dismiss();
    mListener.onAccessGrant(access_token);
    super.onPostExecute(access_token);
}

// Calls a URI and returns the answer as a JSON object
private JSONObject executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception {
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(uri);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse resLogin = client.execute(req);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resLogin
            .getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s = null;
    while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(s);
    }

    return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
}
}

 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
    AccessTokenRequestListener, ImageRequestListener {

private com.example.mikhail.testfsq.EasyFoursquareAsync async;
private ImageView userImage;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
private TextView userName;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);
    userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   //ask for access
    async = new EasyFoursquareAsync(this);
    async.requestAccess(this);
}
@Override
public void onError(String errorMsg) {
  // Do something with the error message
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
   @Override
   public void onAccessGrant(String accessToken) {
  // with the access token you can perform any request to foursquare.
 // example:
    async.getUserInfo(new UserInfoRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(String errorMsg) {
   // Some error getting user info
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(User user) {
     // OWww. did i already got user!?
            if (user.getBitmapPhoto() == null) {
                UserImageRequest request = new UserImageRequest(
                        MyActivity.this, MyActivity.this);
                request.execute(user.getPhoto());
            } else {
                userImage.setImageBitmap(user.getBitmapPhoto());
            }
            userName.setText(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Got it!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
      //for another examples uncomment lines below:
       //requestTipsNearby();
    checkin();
}
@Override
public void onImageFetched(Bitmap bmp) {
    userImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
private void requestTipsNearby() {
    Location loc = new Location("");
    loc.setLatitude(40.4363483);
    loc.setLongitude(-3.6815703);
    TipsCriteria criteria = new TipsCriteria();
    criteria.setLocation(loc);
    async.getTipsNearby(new TipsRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(String errorMsg) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTipsFetched(ArrayList<Tip> tips) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, tips.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, criteria);
}
private void checkin() {
    CheckInCriteria criteria = new CheckInCriteria();
    criteria.setBroadcast(CheckInCriteria.BroadCastType.PUBLIC);
    criteria.setVenueId("4c7063da9c6d6dcb9798d27a");
    async.checkIn(new CheckInListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckInDone(Checkin checkin) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, checkin.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String errorMsg) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, criteria);
}
```

Comment: You'll want to copy and paste the code for `MyActivity.onError` and `com.example.mikhail.testfsq.tasks.AccessTokenRequest` for us to be able to help debug the problem in your code. Right now, it looks like you are creating a handler inside of a thread that's causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I changed and add code, but I can't understand anything...